# Why don't you put a semicolon after HTML and CSS tags?

Tags: html, css, styling

When you link your stylesheet to your document

```
<link type ="text/css" rel ="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
```

why don't you put a semicolon after each attribute, when you put a semicolon after each attribute when doing something like inline styling e.g.

```
<p style="font family:Arial; color:yellow; etc
```

?

Comment: That should be `font-family`, otherwise it's an invalid syntax.

Comment: Hi peters2k14, welcome to StackOverflow. Please note that you talk to other people who try to help you. So please try to formulate and format your question reasonably well so that other people can read it easier. At least read once your whole question before submitting it. One pattern that I use for questions quite often is: 1. I know XY 2. I want to do XY / get to know XY (this is not necessary in this case) 3. Question 4. I've tried XY to answer it myself. (also not necessary in this case).

Comment: Hi Moose, thanks for the constructive criticism  I really appreciate it, I'll take it on board for future questions.

Answer (score 6):

Attributes in HTML are not the same as properties in CSS. They are completely different languages and therefore have completely separate syntaxes. In HTML you're creating a link. In CSS you're creating a `property: value;` pair.

When you put style inline, as per your second bit of code, you're basically telling the browser that you're writing CSS and that it needs to parse it as such. In doing so you then have to use CSS syntax, not HTML.

Comment: Ah thanks a lot that's amazing! I'm a day new so just trying to grasp the fundamentals that's really helpful!

Comment: Technically, in CSS, the semicolon is a separator, not terminator. It is not part of a declaration but separates a declaration from the next declaraton. So `style="font family:Arial; color yellow"` would be OK. But a trailing semicolon is allowed; it would mean that there is an empty declaration after it.